# How to provide something like nil to this parameter?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a parameter like this:

```
rightOperand:(const NSDecimal*)rightOperand
```

how could I provide a value that represents "nothing" or "empty"? would that be void?
i.e.

```
[myObj rightOperand:void];
```

or something different? Or is that impossible for structs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A null C pointer is simply `NULL`.

Comment: Note that while this works for the function he describes (NSDecimal-handling functions), it may cause a crash in other similar functions due to the dereferencing of a NULL pointer.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on what the documentation says/how the function is written.